# Getting the first child in table with same classes?

Tags: css

Im trying to insert an image to a Table :before class by calling the first child on the table. The table has a few different classes and a few duplicates. The class Im trying to work out is

```
td.familyHeader.foldedlabel.Apple:first-child
```

which has a few duplicates, and the first-class removes all of them. How can I call only the first one?

The html:

```
 <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="10" class="familyHeader foldedlabel Apple"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="10" class="familyHeader foldedlabel Apple"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="10" class="familyHeader foldedlabel Apple"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="10" class="familyHeader foldedlabel"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="10" class="familyHeader foldedlabel"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="10" class="familyHeader foldedlabel"></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: you can use :nth-child(1) instead of first-child

Answer (score 0):

you can use below example to create your own code. It will work.

```
<style>
table td.aaa {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
table td:first-child.aaa {
    color:#ff0000
}
</style>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="aaa">1</td>
    <td class="aaa">1</td>
    <td class="aaa">1</td>
    <td class="aaa">1</td>
    <td class="aaa">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly:

Because each `td` is the only child in each `tr` - it will always be the first child in your selector.

instead you need to select the first `tr` and then the td within that

The selector you need will be:

```
tbody tr:first-child td.Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the selector `tbody tr:nth-child(1) td.Apple`.

You can find an example here: [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/nilure/11/edit).